# $_SESSION enable content - PHP

Tags: php, session

I have 3 pages:
-login
-home
-another page

In the login one, I initialize the $ _SESSION:

```
$_SESSION['admin'];
```

after submit login form, redirecting to home
in the top of file, my code is:

home.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {?>

write content if $_SESSION is true

<?php }else{ ?>

write content if $_SESSION it's false

<?php } ?>
```

and this works well once yes and no once, if then from the home, I go to the other page, always following this code, I always get the false result

How do I initialize the $ _SESSION in the login page to make it always valid?

I thought it was also an unfinished $ _SESSION problem

logout.php:

```
<?php
session_unset('admin');
header("location: index.php?sd=Y");
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "index.php";
</script>
```

Comment: Include `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the very top of every page before the first  whitespace to maintain the session across all pages

Comment: @tshimkus not work same

Comment: Do you not get an error or warning from `$_SESSION['admin'];`? Something like `Undefined index: admin`? You aren't really setting the variable, but `$_SESSION['admin'] = 1;` or `$_SESSION['admin'] = TRUE;` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st You should save user credentials that you wants for further usage if User inputs for username and password matched with DB records with  **$_SESSION**

```
    include("..\includefiles\db.php");

    $email =$_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE email ='$email' AND password =  '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query ($con,$sql);
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


     $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['id'];
     $_SESSION['NAME'] = $row['name'];
     $_SESSION['ROLE'] = $row['role'];

     if($_SESSION['ROLE']=='a'){

      header("Location: ..\dashBoard.php");
    }else{
      header("Location: ..\index.php");
    }
```

After saving sessions all you have to do is to start the session with

> session_start()

function in each page. Please note that **session_start()** function must be the **very first** thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.And then check the availability of the session and if session not set redirect to the login page. See the below code.

```
 <?php
    session_start();

   if(isset($_SESSION["ROLE"])){    

   }else{
           header("Location: login.php");
       }

   ?>   
      <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Hope that you may able to grab something from this.