# Session does not redirect

Tags: php, session

I have a login page that when checking the database if the user exists, does not redirect to the panel
The problem is in the session because without it it works correctly

```
if($sql->RowCount()>0){

    $entrou = $_SESSION['entrou'];
    header('location: painel.php');
```

And here we have the check, if the session was not created, it is automatically because the login was not made, and if there is no session, redirects to the login

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION['entrou']) == true ) {
  unset($_SESSION['entrou']);
  header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Make sure you `session_start()`

Comment: It is started correctly

Comment: Please elaborate further. From the info provided, I can't see where is the problem. Why do you need to `$entrou = $_SESSION['entrou']`? BTW you add to session array like `$_SESSION['entrou'] = "foo"` and then access the value from other pages to see if the user is signed in.

Comment: @DigitalOcean check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119955/session-enable-content-php/56120347#56120347

Comment: Your question makes no sense. I don't know where to start. For one, in your second code segment, you say: If `$_SESSION['entrou']` is not set then unset it. That's something like: If I my car is gone then I can finally sell it.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you have to start your session at the beginning of every file you want to use sessions.

If you want to set a session use this:

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION[NAME] = VALUE;
```

and to redirect after you checked if the session is set you can do like that:

```php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION[NAME]){
   header(‘Location: index.php‘;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
// ensure to add session_start at the beginning of 
// all scripts that require use of $_SESSION[]
session_start();

if($sql->rowCount()){
    $entrou = $_SESSION['entrou'];
    header('location: panel.php');
}

if(isset($_SESSION['entrou'])){
    unset($_SESSION['entrou']);
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here try this

```
<?php

session_start();

...

if($sql->RowCount()>0){

   $_SESSION['entrou'] = true;
   header('location: panel.php');
}
else {
    header('location: index.php'); // "no user in the db!"
}

...

if (!isset($_SESSION['entrou']) {
    header('location: index.php');
}

?>
```

But of course if you want to check if the user exists in the database you sould do something like this

```
<?php

$data = $sql->query('SELECT * WHERE username=$_SESSION["username"]') // where "username" is the username column

if ($data == "") {
    header('location: index.php'); // user is non-existent
}
else {
    header('location: panel.php'); // the user is in the database
}
// note this only applies if you're using SQLite
```